# Pass detailrow reference in kendo grid template funciton

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, jquery-templates

Hi is there any way to pass detailRow reference to a function using kendo grid template column?

Here is my trail.

```
  function detailInit(e) {
            detailRow = e.detailRow;
          detailRow.find("#mygrid").kendoGrid({
                    dataSource: {
                        data: empModel,
                    },
                    columns: [
                    {
                        field: "empId",
                        title: "Emp ID",
                        template: '<a href="\\#" onclick="showEmpDetails(\'#= detailRow #\')">        }
                           ]
                 });
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to place every detailRow you retrieve at the `detailInit` into globally located array, then pass this index to your click method (or some sort of key - could be dictionary, rows has uid) and then make the method to read the row details from your array/collection based on the id you have passed in. (Ideally read the row details directly from your datasource by the uid, no need to duplicate the data.) Please refer to below code as pseudo code, I didn't have a chance to run it.

```
var rows = new Array(); 

$('.clickable').click(function () {
     // get the id for your detail
     var detailId = this.attr('detailId');
     // pass it further
     showEmpDetails(detailId);
});

function detailInit(e) {
      detailRow = e.detailRow;
      // add roe to your (cache) collection
      rows[rows.legth] =  detailRow ;
      detailRow.find("#mygrid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {data: empModel},
            columns: [
                {
                    field: "empId",
                    title: "Emp ID",
                    // add attribute onto your a tag
                    template: '<a href="\\#" detailId = "#= rows.legth #" class="clickable">' 
                }
                      ]
             });
});

function showEmpDetails(id) {
     // read from your collection and do what you need
     console.log(rows[id]);
}
```

Comment: I think this is fine. But can we do this without storing in a global array? Is there any solution?

Comment: Yes there is, instead of using global array refer directly to datasource.data() by uid. Problem with this solution is you will have to iterate through data() to find your row, which might take quite some time as well as uid is a guid, not the best choice for html tag exposure. I would at least do a look up for the index as shown above and the uid, eg you would still store the actual data in the datasource, but get them via dictionary of uid and array index/key.